# Arabic text, retrieved from database using soap webservice, does not displaying if it comes after a special character or english text in swift

Tags: ios, swift

If the return value I got from *WebService* has a special character or English text followed by Arabic text, then Arabic text wont show

For example:

`text = "Hello مرحبا" or "Hello | مرحبا"`

It will show like this

`// Hello or Hello |`

[image]

In this picture there are the result values. If you look at the  tag, it contains English text followed by Arabic text
when I call this the result values will contain only the english text.

How can solve this issue?

For making a request and parsing xml, I am using this tool  [gen4swift](http://gen4swift.com/)

Here is the code viewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    branchArray = webservice.BindSalesOrderBranches()
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    self.pickerview = pickerView
    if pickerView == branchPickerView{
        return branchArray[row].Branch
    }
}
```

Here is the request call to the webservice

```
public func BindSalesOrderBranches()-> [SalesModel]{
    var soapReqXML:String = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"

    soapReqXML  += "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\""
    soapReqXML  += " xmlns:xsd =\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\""
    soapReqXML  += " xmlns:soap =\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
    soapReqXML += " <soap:Body>"
    soapReqXML += "<BindSalesOrderBranches xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
    soapReqXML += "</BindSalesOrderBranches>"
    soapReqXML += "</soap:Body>"
    soapReqXML += "</soap:Envelope>"

    let soapAction :String = "http://tempuri.org/BindSalesOrderBranches"

    let responseData:Data = SoapHttpClient.callWS(Host : self.Host,WebServiceUrl:self.Url,SoapAction:soapAction,SoapMessage:soapReqXML)
    let returnValue:[SalesModel] = SalesArrFromXML(data : responseData)
    return returnValue
}

public class func callWS(Host:String,WebServiceUrl:String, SoapAction:String, SoapMessage:String)-> Data{
    self.Error = nil;
    self.ErrorString = nil;
    self.StatusCode = nil;
    self.StatusDescription = nil;
    self.ResponseData = nil;
    self.ResponseString = nil;

    var responseData : Data = Data()

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 0)
    let url = URL.init(string: WebServiceUrl)
    let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    req.httpMethod = "POST"
    req.httpBody = SoapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
    req.addValue(Host, forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    req.addValue("text/xml;charset =utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let contentLength = SoapMessage.utf8.count
    req.addValue(String(contentLength), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    req.addValue(SoapAction, forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

    let task_ = session.dataTask(with: req as URLRequest){ (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response{
            print("Response = \(response)")
        }
        self.Error=error

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            self.StatusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                self.StatusCode=httpResponse.statusCode
                self.ErrorString=httpResponse.description

                responseData = Data()
                self.ResponseData = Data()
            } else {
                responseData = data!
                self.ResponseData = data
                let responseString =  String.init(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                self.ResponseString = responseString!
            }
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    task_.resume()

    semaphore.wait()
    return responseData
}

public func SalesArrFromXML(data: Data)-> [SalesModel] {

    let xmlToParse   = String.init(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    return SalesArrFromXMLString( xmlToParse : xmlToParse)
}

public func SalesArrFromXMLString(xmlToParse:String)->[SalesModel] {

    let xml = SWXMLHash.lazy(xmlToParse)
    let xmlRoot = xml.children.first
    let xmlBody = xmlRoot?.children.last
    let xmlResponse: XMLIndexer? = xml.children.first?.children.first?.children.first
    let xmlResult0: XMLIndexer?  = xmlResponse?.children.last
    var strVal = ""
    var elemName = ""
    var returnValue:[SalesModel] = [SalesModel]()
    if elemName == "" {
        // Array Property For returnValue
        let itemCount1: Int = (xmlResult0?.children.count)!
        for i1 in 0 ..< itemCount1 {
            let rItem1 = SalesModel()
            let xmlResult_Parent1:XMLIndexer? = xmlResult0?.children[i1]
            let childCount1 :Int = (xmlResult_Parent1?.children.count)!
            for j1 in 0 ..< childCount1 {

                let xmlResult1: XMLIndexer? =  xmlResult_Parent1?.children[j1]
                let elem1: XMLElement? =  xmlResult1?.element
                strVal = ""
                if elem1?.children.first is TextElement {
                    let elemText:TextElement = elem1?.children.first as! TextElement
                    strVal = elemText.text

                }
                elemName = elem1!.name
                // Array Propert of returnValue subProperty for rItem1
                if elemName == "Branch" {
                    rItem1.Branch =  strVal
                }
            }
            returnValue.append(rItem1)
        }
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [mcve] to make it on-topic.

Comment: In this case, an URL is all we need.

Comment: I have edited the question